# Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `coding`. x no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "character"

Tags: r, select, tidyverse

I'm at my wits end. I'm trying to do a rather simple mutate in my pipeline, but for one particular example R just refuses to work. I'm sorry, but I can't provide a reproducible example (for the reasons mentioned below).

So this is my full pipeline:

```
new <- old %>%
  left_join(., lookup, by = "id") %>%
  mutate(sum_0.95   = apply(across(starts_with("pred")), 1, function(x) {sum(x >= 0.95 & x < 1)}),
         sum_le_0.5 = apply(across(starts_with("pred")), 1, function(x) {sum(x <= 0.5 & x > 0)}),
         coding = case_when(pred_QC4A_code_10 == 0 | pred_QC4A_code_10 == 1 ~ "ABC",
                            sum_0.95 > 0 & (sum_0.95 + sum_le_0.5 == (lookup %>% select(starts_with("pred")) %>% names() %>% length())) ~ "DEF",
                            TRUE ~ "XYZ")) %>%
  select(-starts_with("pred"), -sum_0.95, -sum_le_0.5)
```

This gives an error message (due to the `lookup %>% select(starts_with("pred")) %>% names() %>% length()` part in the case_when).

```
# Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `coding`.
# x no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "character"
```

The problem is:

- the exact same structure/code example works fine with a different data set
- if I replace the problematic part with just the numeric result of it (29), it works
- if I replace `lookup` with a different data set of the same structure, it works
- if I do `test <- lookup` and replace the lookup by test in the pipeline, it works
- if I do `test <- dput(lookup)`, same as above, it works

The checks for `identical(test, lookup)` also return `TRUE`.

This is also the reason why I can't provide you with a working example. Because whatever I do (e.g. dput), the error is not reproducible anymore.

Here's at least the `str(lookup)` result

```
'data.frame':   5625 obs. of  30 variables:
 $ id                 : chr  "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_10  : num  1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_11  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_12  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_13  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_14  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_15  : num  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_16  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_17  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_20  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_21  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_22  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_23  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_30  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_31  : num  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_32  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_33  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_34  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_40  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_41  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_42  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_43  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_44  : num  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_80  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_995 : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_996 : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_997 : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_998 : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_9991: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pred_QC4A_code_9992: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

I think it really has to do with the `select` command, but no idea, what's going on.

---

Update: solved the problem. The issue was that in my `new` data frame, I also have a column called `lookup`, so the case_when is accessing this column instead of the external data set, which of course doesn't work then.

Comment: I guess you need `c_across`.  Can you show a small reproducible example

Comment: Where/why would I need c_across? I thought case_when is vectorized already?

Comment: I see that you are applying `apply` before the `case_when`

Comment: Yes, this part is totally fine, the first two mutates run perfectly fine. It's really this part: `lookup %>% select(starts_with("pred")) %>% names() %>% length()` within the case_when - even though it works under the different circumstances I mentioned above.

Comment: You could take it out of it and check what exactly is the output

Comment: the output is exactly 29. `str(lookup %>% select(starts_with("pred")) %>% names() %>% length())` gives `int 29`.

Comment: I would assume that is not going to change in every row.  So, you may create a new object i.e. `l1 <- lookup %>% select(starts_with("pred")) %>% names() %>% length()` and use the `l1` in the comparison

Comment: Yes, that's the workaround I'm currently using. Yet, this is frustrating, because it actually should work and I've no idea why it doesn't. It feels like giving up.

Comment: I would use proper parentheses to separate the comparison because of precedence of operators i.e. `(sum_le_0.5 == (lookup %>% select(starts_with("pred")) %>% names() %>% length()))`

Comment: Please note that when you are posting questions without a proper example, it is difficult for others to test

Comment: Sure, the condition, however, would actually be `(sum_0.95 + sum_le_0.5) == (lookup ...)`

Comment: And again, I would provide an example if it actually reproduces the error, but as I said, any attempt of e.g. dput or creating a manual toy example makes my code work. Even things like `test_lookup <- lookup` makes the code work.

Comment: If the issue is only on the larger data and not on the subset, it must be related to the data itself.  I would wrap the conditions separately within `()` to make sure that it is not precedence issue

Comment: I thought so as well and checked the brackets and all, but this is just fine. Also it can#t be the data itself, because the running it externally, the correct result (29) is returned (as can also be seen from the str(lookup) example). And it also shoudln't work with the test_lookup <- lookup check, but it does. So from this longer discussion, I probably take away that you also don't see an immediate bug/typo/obvious misuse of commands?

Comment: except for the `(sum_0.95 + sum_le_0.5 ==`

Comment: Or may be wrap the `lookup %>% select(starts_with("pred"))` within `{}`

Comment: Oh my, I just realized what' the problem. In my real `new` data set, I have a column called `lookup`. So this now makes sense because R would treat the `lookup` part in the case_when as if I want to use the column and not the external data set.

Comment: If someone wants to close the thread, feel free.

Comment: If that is that case you need to use `!!lookup %>% .

Comment: >so you don't value somebody trying to help solve your question?

not sure what you mean? I defintely value the discussion here and the effort you put in, because it made me double-check my code/data again. (I was not yet able to hit the voting button).

Comment: It is a reaction to your comment about closing the thread.

Comment: No, this was just because the question was based on an issue that is not visible in the question itself and hence not reproducible for others. Doesn't mean that the discussion wasn't helpful.

Comment: Its okay.  when somebody doesn't show a reproducible example, it is a bit more hard for the person checking the code why it didn't work.  That was the reason I said wouldn't that count or not.  No issue. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be better to create an object outside as it is a fixed

```
v1 <- lookup %>%
        select(starts_with("pred")) %>% 
        names() %>% 
        length()
```

Then, we could simplify it

```
...
 coding = case_when(pred_QC4A_code_10 == 0 | pred_QC4A_code_10 == 1 ~ "ABC",
                        sum_0.95 > 0 & ((sum_0.95 + sum_le_0.5) == (v1))) ~ "DEF",
                        TRUE ~ "XYZ"))
```

---

OP mentioned there is a column named 'lookup' in the dataset.  So, if we need to use the object from the global env, instead of the column, escape (`!!`)

```
 new <- old %>%
  left_join(., lookup, by = "id") %>%
  mutate(sum_0.95   = apply(across(starts_with("pred")), 1, function(x) {sum(x >= 0.95 & x < 1)}),
         sum_le_0.5 = apply(across(starts_with("pred")), 1, function(x) {sum(x <= 0.5 & x > 0)}),
         coding = case_when(pred_QC4A_code_10 == 0 | pred_QC4A_code_10 == 1 ~ "ABC",
                            sum_0.95 > 0 & (sum_0.95 + sum_le_0.5 == (!!lookup %>% select(starts_with("pred")) %>% names() %>% length())) ~ "DEF",
                            TRUE ~ "XYZ")) %>%
  select(-starts_with("pred"), -sum_0.95, -sum_le_0.5)
```